# runtime error although i am getting the expected output

Tags: c++

My solution to a [CodeChef problem.](https://www.codechef.com/problems/CONFLIP)

I ran this code in turbo c++ in my computer and in codechef, they are using gcc compiler.

Please help me to get out of this runtime error.

### My code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class game
{
    public:
        int i,q;
        long n;
        long a[1000000000];
        long h,t;
        int in();
        int out();

};
int game::in()
{
    cin>>i>>n>>q;
    if(i==1)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
            a[k]=1;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
            a[k]=2;
    }
    for(int r=1;r<=n;r++)
    {
        for(int p=0;p<r;p++)
        {
            if(a[p]==1)
                a[p]=2;
            else
                a[p]=1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int game::out()
{
    for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
    {
        if(a[x]==1)
            h++;
        else
            t++;
    }
    if(q==1)
        cout<<endl<<h;
    else
        cout<<endl<<t;
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    game s[10][20000];
    int t,g;
    cin>>t;
    for(int l=0;l<t;l++)
    {
        cin>>g;
        for(int j=0;j<g;j++)
        {
            s[l][j].in();
        }
    }
    for(int l=0;l<t;l++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<g;j++)
            s[l][j].out();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `game` object contains a `long` array of 1 billion elements. Assuming a 64-bit computer, that is already 8GB of memory. In your `main` function you allocate 200,000 instances of `game`, for a total memory usage of 1600TB. I don't think your poor computer has that much memory.